# awk sorting according one colum but must be printed all of them

Tags: sorting, awk

i can find any way may someone open my mind

```
awk '{$3=cet print $0 }' < sort < awk '{cet=$3 }' file.txt
```

input

```
 1  00A0asd4426         18/10/2014 09:08:50 
 2  00A0Bsdfsdf         No data found
 3  0asdasdsda3         25/10/2014 10:31:53
```

output

```
  1 00A0asd4426         18/10/2014 09:08:50
  3 0asdasdsda3         25/10/2014 10:31:53 
  2 00A0Bsdfsdf         No data found
```

Comment: Better add sample input/output. We dunno if it's floats, integers, strings...

Comment: Also, check the `-t` and `-k` option of `sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical approach to do it is using `sort -k` :

```
$ cat l
a d 1
b c 2
c b 3
```

test :

```
$ sort -k2 l
c b 3
b c 2
a d 1
```

Use the `-n` switch if you treat numbers and `-t DEL` whete **DEL** is your own delimiter (space by default)

Answer (score 1):

I think for this you should use the [sort](/questions/tagged/sort) unix tool.

For example if one want to sort by the second column as a number, this could be used:

```
sort -k2n inputfile
```

Input file:

```
aaa 123 xxx
bbbxxx 1 yyy
xxxccc 0 zzz
ddd 15 xx
```

Output:

```
xxxccc 0 zzz
bbbxxx 1 yyy
xxxccc 1 aaa
ddd 15 xx
aaa 123 xxx
```

Or You can use string comparison:

```
sort -k2 inputfile
```

Output:

```
xxxccc 0 aaa
xxxccc 0 zzz
bbbxxx 1 yyy
aaa 123 xxx
ddd 15 xx
```

Using `-t` the separator could be set. Default is whitespace. Using `-s` it can be made stable sort. And there are a lot more possibilities. Reading [man sort(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort) may help!

I hope this helps!